# How to display Max using groovy expression in adf

Tags: java, groovy, oracle-adf

I need to find max salary and displaying in new attribute.

Employee table has following columns:

```
  Id,
  Name,
  Salary
```

I have added new add transient variable with groovy expression using Edit Expression Editor :

```
    max(Salary)
```

to display max salary which exists in whole table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried this example in 11g.

Table : Emp :

```
    E_ID    EMP_NAME    E_SAL
     2         emp2     5000000
     4         e5       100000
     5         emp2     300000
     6         emp3     250000
     7         emp3     100000
     8         emp3     100000
     3          eee     250000
     1          emp     100000
```

In which E_ID - 2 has max salary as 5000000.

Now coming back to ADF:

I have created EMP table EO and VO both.

```
 EMPEO
 EMPVO - EmpView
```

Now in EmpView has all the attributes as Eid, EmpName, Esal.

Created a ViewAccessor of Same VO (EmpView) in EmpView

```
     - Click on EmpView.

     - Go to View Accessor. Click on Green plus symbol. Add the EmpView from left to right. It will be named as EmpView1.
```

- Create a transient variable named as maxSal. Give a groovy expression
  to it in a Expression component.

  ```
   EmpView1.max("Esal")
  ```
- Now,create a jsff page and add EmpView as Form or table (as per your
  requirement) with newly created transient variable. Run the
  application. It's working in my case.

Hope this may help.